# differential equation, chain rule problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $u$ be a function defined on $\mathbb R^3$ such that $u(x,y,z)=\phi(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})$, where $\phi \in C^2$.

(i) Show that $\Delta u +u=0$ if and only if $$\phi(r)''+\frac{2}{r}\phi'(r)+\phi(r)=0.$$

(ii) Consider the substitution $\psi(r)=r\phi(r)$, find a solution of $\Delta u +u=0$  with the condition $u(0,0,0)=1.$

I got stuck at part (ii). For (i), I've defined $r:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ as $r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Then $u(x,y,z)=\phi \circ r(x,y,z)$. After some calculations one arrives to the identity $$\Delta u +u=\phi(r)''+\frac{2}{r}\phi'(r)+\phi(r)$$

From there it follows directly the two implications.

I don't know how to solve the differential equation in (ii), I would appreciate some help.

Comment: As part (i) showed, a solution to the 2nd-order ODE you found will also solve $\Delta u+u=0$. Try plugging the substitution suggested into that 2nd-order ODE, and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the suggested substitution, namely, let $\phi(r) = \psi(r)/r$. Then $$\phi'(r) = -\psi(r)/r^2 + \psi'(r)/r,$$ $$\phi''(r) = 2\psi(r)/r^3 -2\psi'(r)/r^2 + \psi''(r)/r.$$

Now plug this into your differential equation to get:

$$ \psi''(r)/r + \psi(r)/r = 0,$$ which reduces to the simple form

$$\psi''(r) = -\psi(r),$$ to which the solution you should know.